# ColorFunction in Graphics

Tags: graphics, color

I have several primitive figures to pass to the Graphics function to draw. These figures are weighed with some values, so I'd like to assign a color in accordance with some *ColorFunction*, say *"TemperatureMap"*. Is it possible to use Graphics like this?

```
tr = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0.25, 0}, {0.125, 0.25}}];
value=0.8;
Graphics[{ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"[value], tr}]
```

Comment: You have a list of `Graphics` primitives, and a list of values?  You'd like for each primitive to have a single color according to its value?

Comment: `Graphics[{ColorData["TemperatureMap"][0.8], tr}]`

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't clear enough from the documentation, that it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you should be aware of the values that the color scheme (TemperatureMap in this case) can take:

```
tr = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0.25, 0}, {0.125, 0.25}}];
Graphics@{ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#], tr} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1]
```

[image]